# Can't download using Sockets java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, stream

I have kinda figured out how sockets work but I seem to have run into another wall. I'm supposed to somehow use the socket to transfer the data, but how? when I try it gives me a SocketException bind, saying it's already in use. I used it originally to connect it to a Directory, where I will gather other nodes and then if one doesn't have the data, it will ask for it from the other nodes.

```
 class Download extends Thread {
CloudByte[] list = new CloudByte[1000000];

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        var nodes = ConnectingDirectory.getNodes();
        for (Nodes node : nodes) {
            if ((node.getHostPort() == ConnectingDirectory.getHostIP())) {
                downloadFile(node.getHostPort());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fileWriting(getFile().getName(), list);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public synchronized void downloadFile(int port) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    while (true) {
        ServerSocket ss = ConnectingDirectory.getServerSocket();
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9999; j += 1) {
            byte[] bit = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < bit.length; i++) {
                list[i + j * 100] = new CloudByte(bit[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Download Completed");

    }
}
```

This is the function, I'm using to Download the date from the InputStream, the problem I'm having is that it's not downloading unless I restart the other Node. Is there a way to avoid having to do that? I really am at a loss.

Note; the for is because I need to transfer 1000000 bytes, in packets of 100 bytes.

The sending the data is:

```
class Upload extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (getFile().exists()) {
            var nodes = ConnectingDirectory.getNodes();
            for (Nodes node : nodes) {
                if (node.getHostPort() == ConnectingDirectory.getHostIP()) {
                    try {
                        uploadFile(node.getHostPort());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            new Download().start();
        }
    }

public static void uploadFile(int hostPort) throws IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", hostPort);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ByteBlockRequest bbr = new ByteBlockRequest(getStoredData());
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9999; j += 1) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(bbr.blocksToSend(j));
    }
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    System.out.println("Uploaded all the Data!");

}
```

Creating the server socket:

```
 public ConnectingDirectory(String hostName, int hostIP, int directoryIP) throws IOException {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.directoryIP = directoryIP;
    ConnectingDirectory.hostIP = hostIP;
    this.address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
    socket = new Socket(address, directoryIP);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(hostIP);
    signUp();
    askConnectedNodes();

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ObjectInputStream` / `ObjectOutputStream` ... and this weird `CloudByte` class?  If you are just transferring data, use the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` APIs.  Specifically `int read(byte[], int, int)` and `void write(byte[], int, int)`.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, not a packet protocol.  You don't send packets, you just send a stream of bytes.  You can send the whole 1,000,000 bytes at once.  The other end might RECEIVE it in pieces, so you have to keep reading until you get the whole thing.

Comment: @StephenC CloudByte is a class that we have to use. It's basically an extra step for byte[]. We just need to convert it back and forth. Plus we were advised to use ObjectInput / ObjectOutput

Comment: (And even if there is a "really good reason" to send packets, you don't want to be using `ObjectInputStream` / `ObjectOutputStream` for that.)

Comment: You should be creating your server socket ONCE, and just call `accept` in your loop.  The server socket itself can accept multiple connections over time.

Comment: Oh ... I see.  This is a homework exercise.  I thought we were talking about a practical real-world program.  If you are doing homework, you really ought to mention that because it will change the advice people give.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hmm interesting, but we need to send "packets" of 100 bytes, so in total, we will need to send 10000 packets, each of 100 bytes. The way it is right now, I can even write the contents to a file, without losing a single Byte, but again, I need to restart the first node, and I can't figure out a way of avoiding to do that

Comment: @StephenC yes, it's not a real-world problem, but I like to think it is, so I can have an idea when I start working haha but ye.

Comment: @StephenC ye, but if I mention it, no one will reply or even care. It's a sad reality unfortunately, I'm not asking for straight-up answers I just want some guidance, because it's extremely confusing and I never used Sockets before. I have been stuck on this for the past 3 days.

Comment: StephenC is right. TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. From the user's point of view, there is no such thing as a "packet". All "packets" (see TX/RX buffers, Nagle's algo, etc.) are about implementation. You have no control over how your data will be split into "packets" for transmission over the network. You should just take InputStream/OutputStream from a socket and work with them using byte buffers-just read and write buffers checking the result (how many bytes were read/written) from the socket and repeat until success/finish. Streaming is a better idea, especially for large files.